# Apache httpclient 4.3.1 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, jboss, httpclient, wildfly

I am developing a Java EE web application.

here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>bitcoin</groupId>
<artifactId>bitcoin</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Chens Bitcoin Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify tested stacks. -->
    <version.jboss.bom>1.0.5.CR6</version.jboss.bom>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Repo</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Define the version of JBoss' Java EE 6 APIs we want to use -->
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including
            a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or
            a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct
            versions of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-security stack
            (you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs with Security).
            You can actually use this stack with any version of JBoss AS that implements
            Java EE 6, not just JBoss AS 7! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-security</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!--<dependency>-->
      <!--<groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>-->
      <!--<artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>-->
      <!--<version>2.2.0</version>-->
  <!--</dependency>-->

  <!--<dependency>-->
      <!--<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>-->
      <!--<artifactId>jsf-spi</artifactId>-->
      <!--<version>1.0</version>-->
  <!--</dependency>-->

  <!-- Rewrite -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
      <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
      <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>3.5</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Data time management -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Import the PicketLink API, we deploy this as library with the application,
        and can compile against it -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketlink-core-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Import the PicketLink implementation, we deploy this as library with the application,
      but can't compile against it -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
      <artifactId>picketlink-core-impl</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <finalName>bitcoin</finalName>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
              <compilerArguments>
                  <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
              </compilerArguments>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <configuration>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>7.4.Final</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>validate</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>copy</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                      <silent>true</silent>
                      <artifactItems>
                          <artifactItem>
                              <groupId>javax</groupId>
                              <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                              <version>7.0</version>
                              <type>jar</type>
                          </artifactItem>
                      </artifactItems>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have a method to create HttpClient, it works fine alone, but having problem when calling from jsf page:

```
  public void doSth() {
  ......
  HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
  ......
  }
```

this method is invoked by commonbutton on JSF page, when button clicked following error occurred:

```
      Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52) [httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56) [httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46) [httpcore-4.3.jar:4.3]
      ......
```

googled it, seems httpclient jar file has conflict with some other class, but I really can't figure out which one, and all dependencies in pom are necessary.

BTW, I am using WildFly 8 CR as server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Smells a lot like a you have two different versions of the httpclient in your classpath. Have you checked if WildFly comes with a httpclient? Other than that, maybe one of your dependencies pulls its own httpclient. Try mvn dependency:tree and check if there are two versions of httpclient

Comment: Also, probably unrelated, you use the "jboss-javaee-6.0-with-security" bom in dependency management, but in your dependencies, you use javaee-web-api-7.0

Answer (score 1):

You should not be mixing EE6 & 7 poms as it can bring you problems in your app.

For starter you should replace

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-security</artifactId>
      <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

With

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-security</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.0</version>
      <type>pom</scope>
      <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

you could also remove:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

as you get all that already as part of jboss-javaee-7.0-with-security pom import
but it does not hurt anyway.

Also replace

```
 <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>7.4.Final</version>
 </plugin>
```

with:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</plugin>
```

as othewise you will have problems with deploying to wildfly, also goal has changed from `jboss-as:deploy` to `wildfly:deploy`

you should be inspecting whole dependency tree if you have any duplicate http client in dependency tree.

you can do that by running

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

it will give you what dependency is bringing in and from where.

As a side note, you should upgrade to WildFly 8.0.0 Final. Not related to your problem but just to get many bugfixes...